# Guzzle Service Description How to have Comma Deliminated Array?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, guzzle, guzzle-service-description

is there a way to automatically have a Guzzle Service Descriptor field, take an array, and it'll parse it to a comma list?

Data

`Array [ "test", "another test" ]`

Service Descriptors

```
{
    "name": "YouTube",
    "baseUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com",
    "apiVersion": "v3",
    "description": "YouTube GData Graph API",
    "operations": {
        "GetVideos": {
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "uri": "/youtube/v3/videos",
            "parameters": {
                "id": {
                    "type":"array",
                    "location":"query",
                    "required": true
                },
                "part": {
                    "location": "query",
                    "default": "snippet"
                },
                "key": {
                    "location": "query",
                    "default": "{MY KEY}",
                    "static": true
                },
                "maxResults": {
                    "location": "query",
                    "default": 50
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The field is the `id` under `parameters`, I'd like to provide the raw php array of strings to that, and have Guzzle automatically convert that to a comma deliminated list

Right now, I have to do this:

```
$command = $this->client->getCommand('GetVideos', [
    'id' => implode(",", array_slice($this->id, 0, 50))
]);
```

Right now, that creates a URL with multiple instances of id

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=test&id=another%20test&part=snippet&key={MY KEY}&maxResults=50`

and I want it to come out like:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=test,another%20test&part=snippet&key={MY KEY}&maxResults=50`

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using guzzle 3 or guzzle 4?

Comment: Guzzle 3.8, is 4 available for production? If it helps, I can upgrade

Comment: Guzzle 4 is production ready, but upgrading wouldn't help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guzzle 3 constructs querystrings from a `Query` object, which has an aggregator. By calling `->setAggregator($aggregator)` on the `Query`, you can override the default behavior. You want to give it an instance of `Guzzle\Http\QueryAggregator\CommaAggregator`.

There isn't much in the Guzzle docs about it, but there is [a brief mention](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-client/request.html#query-string-parameters).

Comment: In the concept of using the service description, as well as the getCommand method, how do I set this? I get back an error when I do this: `$command = $this->client->getCommand('GetVideos', [
            'id' => array_slice($this->id, 0, 50)
        ])->getRequest()->getQuery()->setAggregator(new \Guzzle\Http\QueryAggregator\CommaAggregator());`  with the error being: `The command must be prepared before retrieving the request `

Comment: You'd have to set up a listener that subscribes to the service and sets the aggregator on its requests before they go out. Take a look at this implementation: https://github.com/bradfeehan/desk-php/blob/master/lib/Desk/Client/CommaAggregatorListener.php